# Razor Pages Partial View: Model is not defined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

TLDR: the problem is, I see the following error when I try to get ID from Model (line 8. of below code):

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Details:

I wanted to make part of my HTML reusable. There is a large div called "InfoBox" that contains some information, which is placed in multiple locations on my website. I decided to create Partial Razor Page. Here is how I made it:

`_TextBoxInfoPartial.cshtml.cs`:

```
public class _TextBoxInfoPartialModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        ID = ""; //default

        return Page();
    }
}
```

`_TextBoxInfoPartial.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model Definicje.Pages.Shared._TextBoxInfoPartialModel

<button type="button" class="visibility-toggler" visibility-toggler="#hint-math@(Model.ID)">Wstaw wzór</button>
<div id="hint-math@(Model.ID)" class="hintbox">
    some text
</div>
```

To place partial in another cshtml file, I use this line:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_TextBoxInfoPartial", new _TextBoxInfoPartialModel { ID = g.ID + "" })
```

I don't understand. I'm specifying Model for Partial, why is it undefined then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the partial view, Remove the `@page` directive.

```
@model Definicje.Pages.Shared._TextBoxInfoPartialModel

<button type="button" class="visibility-toggler" 
                  visibility-toggler="#hint-math@(Model.ID)">Wstaw wzór</button>
<div id="hint-math@(Model.ID)" class="hintbox">
    some text
</div>
```

Now `Model` will be the `_TextBoxInfoPartialModel` object you are passing from the other view.

When you add the `@page` directive to the view file, it starts to behave differently, more like an action method - you can access it via an http request.

Another observation is, if your file name starts with `_` prefix, the routing capability mentioned above will not work. It cannot be directly accessed by an Http request.

So for your partial views, do not use `@page` directive